# Letter Overlap Issue Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, lettering

I'm trying to make a logo in illustraot using this font:

http://www.dafont.com/pokemon.font

Unfortunately, when I add a stroke, it ruins the overlapping on the font. For example, I want the blue stroke on the 'O' in overlap to be behind the 'v'. Any thoughts on how to accomplsih this?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Remove the stroke from the objects.

Group the objects (letters).

Use the **Appearance Panel** to add a stroke to the **group**.

Move the stroke *below* the `Contents` item in the **Appearance Panel**.

[image]

If the text is "live" text, you don't need to group it, just add the stroke via the **Appearance Panel** -- See here ---> [How can I add multiple concentric outlines around text?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8996/how-can-i-add-multiple-concentric-outlines-around-text)

Answer (score 2):

The best way to keep formatting and using it as text is use the Appearance panel `shift + f6`.
You can select your object (the group of text, not with the `Type Tool`) and open the appearance panel. In the appearance panel you choose to 'add new fill' (bottom left) and you can select your fill colour, and your stroke colour. Then simply drag the stroke layer *below* the fill layer like you would any other layers (for some reason this doesn't work when using the appearance panel to edit the text directly after selecting with the Type Tool).

Answer (score 0):

The way I have always handled that situation is by duplicating the text layer in my layers palette and naming the bottom layer 'text stroke only', and the text layer as a "text fill only".  This way I can adjust the size of my stroke In the bottom layer and the fill layer above it always appears the same.

[image]

What I do next is highlight both layers then I select my little drop-down menu and choose "collect in new layer"

[image]

This way I can just select the whole text group as if they are just one item and not have to worry about future adjustments like aligning them with other objects or whatever.

[image]