# Illustrator: Creating a stroke around blend? Or other method?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

Hi, I'm trying to recreate, in Illustrator, two parts of this logo's treatment: 1. the smooth blend from the front to the back and 2. the single stroke around the final complex shape. For now, I'm ignoring the inside white stroke of the "front" yellow version of the logo and also the grey highlights.

With what I know of Illustrator, I'm trying to do the pop-out/3D effect using the blend tool.  This looks fine if I just want to go with that, but I get into trouble when I try to create that single, white outline of the whole shape.  It's that single outline that I'm really trying to figure out.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: THere is no real point in doing this with a blend.

Comment: See: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13564/what-are-some-good-tips-on-how-to-extrude-text-in-adobe-illustrator and https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8996/how-can-i-add-multiple-concentric-outlines-around-text

Comment: Thank you, Scott and @joojaa.  The first link in Scott's comment is the most helpful.  I had a feeling that blend wasn't the way to go to be able to get a single shape.

What I'm now finding is that while I can use the shape builder to make the extruded letters for U and N, the O is proving to be difficult.  The issue I'm bumping into is that I'm trying to build the fill-in areas for the pair of O's by creating a line that is tangent to both but it's not simple.  Will persevere, but I have my basic steps for the original question answered.  Thank you!

Comment: use the common tangents script by hiryoki sato. See https://shanfan.github.io/Illustrator-Scripts-Archive/

Comment: @EatingIsInMyHeredity Outline mode (View > Outline) can be exceptionally helpful when aligning paths.

Answer (score 0):

for the outline you wanna create an offset path - ungroup it and leave it as the back, but that would be the last step, when you finish the 3D pop out effect, duplicate it Ctrl+C then Ctrl+F, expand the one below, and lock the one on top so you dont mess it up. Pathfinder join everything together, then do the offset path

Dor the pop out you'll have to duplicate the text, and use the blend tool, don't use it myself, I just connect the end to the top text and do it like that.